# iphone sdk, Generating a .pdf file using data from text fields of a registration form

Tags: iphone

I have to  generate a .pdf file using data from text fields of a registration form. I searched all around but didn't get any relevant solution. All answers are to draw a line or image or single string.

Thanks in advance.